# In a lottery of $90$ numbers a man adds extra $1,2,3$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider a lottery where $5$ balls are chosen randomly among $90$ balls numbered from $1$ to $90$. A man cheats adding to the $90$ balls, before the draw, three more balls numbered $1,2,3$. We say that he will *get busted* if among the five balls chosen, at least two have the same numbers. We say that he *wins* if at least three drawn balls have numbers $1,2,3$.

1) What is the probability he will get busted?

2) What is the probability he will win?

---

Considering ordered $5$-tuples and after a lot of counting, for $1)$ I obtain $$ \dfrac{5}{713} - \dfrac{1}{194649} = \dfrac{44}{6279}$$
and for $2)$
$$ \dfrac{3442}{5774587}.$$
I am especially dubious regarding point $2)$.
Is there a clever and faster way to solve these?

Comment: Hard to say, since you didn't show us *your* way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count by considering the originals and their counterfeits to be distinct in fact though not appearance.

**Busted:** Draw at least one of $\{1,2,3\}$ twice in 5 balls out of 93.

There are ${93 \choose 5}$ ways to choose 5 balls in 93, in total.

We need one of the pair of balls to turn up. There are ${3 \choose 1}$ choices of pairs and ${91\choose 3}$ equi-probable ways to select the rest.

Also, we need to exclude the case of 2 pairs turning up.  There are ${3 \choose 2}$ choices of pairs and ${89 \choose 1}$ equi-probable ways to choose the rest.

$$\mathcal{Pr}(\text{busted})= \frac{{3\choose 1}{91 \choose 3}-{3\choose 2}{89\choose 1}}{93 \choose 5} = \frac{44}{6279} \approx 0.007007\dotsc $$

**"Win"**: Draw all of $\{1,2,3\}$ exactly once in 5 balls out of 93.

There are $2^3$ ways to draw a 'win' and $87\choose 2$ ways to draw the rest (that don't include doubles).$$\mathcal{Pr}(\text{win})=\dfrac{2^3{87\choose 2}}{93\choose 5} = \dfrac{9976}{17323761} \approx 0.000576\dotsc$$

---

**Edit:**
Well, that is unless you can 'win' while 'busted'; which does appear to be the case.

If so, we have to include the cases where 1 or 2 of the winning numbers turn up; which means the numbers can be 3,4,or 5 of the selected 5.
$$\frac{{6\choose 3}{87\choose 2}+{6\choose 4}{87\choose 1}+ {6\choose 5}}{93\choose 5}=\frac{8459}{5774587}\approx 0.001465\dotsc$$

---

**Edit 2:**  When the win condition is read as "each of 1,2,3 to appear at least once".

$$\frac{2^3{87\choose 2} + {3\choose 1}2^2{87\choose 1} + {3\choose 2}2^1}{93\choose 5}=\frac{3442}{5774587}\approx 0.0005961\dotsc$$

Comment: Actually in the *win* condition repetitions are allowed...

Comment: @HenningMakholm The order of the draws is not considered in the calculations

Comment: @user130753, I presumed you can't win if you are busted.  However, you're right, it does say "at least three balls have 1,2,3". Huh!

Comment: @user: Hm, you're right.

Comment: Why only three winning were $2^3 \binom{87}{2}$ while in the edit they are $\binom{6}{3} \binom{87}{2}$?

Comment: Wait. Does a win need each of 1,2,and 3 to turn up at least once?

Comment: Yes it does. For example $\lbrace 1,2,3,89,90 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,2,2,3,3 \rbrace$ are wins, $\lbrace 1,2,2,89,90 \rbrace $ is not.

Comment: You have the same problem with $\binom{6}{4}$, where you count also $\lbrace 1,1,2,2 \rbrace$, which is not winning.

Comment: The numerator should be $$ 2^3 \binom{87}{2} + \left(\binom{6}{4} - \binom{3}{2}\right) \binom{87}{1} + \binom{6}{5}. $$ Right?

Comment: Ok it's the same. Thanks!

Comment: Select one of each three pairs, and 2 from the rest; OR select a whole pair from one of the three, and one of each of the other two pairs and 1 from the rest; OR select two of the pairs, and one of the other pair and none of the rest.  $2^3{87\choose 2}+{3\choose 1}2^2{87\choose 1}+{3\choose 2}2^1$